# Thread.sleep method changes desired outcome

Tags: java

I have some code here for a project. It works as expected BEFORE implementing the sleep method. Then when I add sleep, it does not show the desired outcome.

I am new to java and not really experienced in using the sleep method.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {    
        //initialize variables for user input on sleep and generations.
        long t;
        double gen;
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the length of time between generations: ");
        t = input.nextLong();

        System.out.print("Enter the number of generations: ");
        gen = input.nextDouble();

        // Create a new GamOfLife object
        GameOfLife g = new GameOfLife();
        char[][] tempBoard = new char[g.getRows()][g.getColumns()];
        // Inialize tempBoard to be all 0 
        for(int d = 0; d < g.getRows(); d++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < g.getColumns(); j++)
                tempBoard[d][j] = '0';          
        }

        // Set board in GameOfLife instance
        g.setGameBoard(tempBoard);
        // Set initial pattern 
        g.putGlider();
        // Print the gameboard with the initial patter
        g.printGameBoard();

        // 100 Generations
        for (int i = 0; i < gen; i++)
        {
            /* Create a temporary board that represents the next generation of cells
               Cannot change the gameboard directly because it will change the 
               number of surrounding neighbors of the cell next to it. */ 
            for(int d = 0; d < g.getRows(); d++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < g.getColumns(); j++)
                    tempBoard[d][j] = '0';          
            }

            for (int r = 0; r < g.getRows();r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < g.getColumns(); c++)
                {
                    // Cell is dead and has 3 neighbors (alive in next generation)
                    if (g.deadOrAlive(r, c) == false && g.getNeighbors(r, c) == 3)
                        tempBoard[r][c] = '1';
                    // Cell is alive and has 2 or 3 neighbors (remains alive for next generation)
                    else if (g.deadOrAlive(r, c) && ((g.getNeighbors(r, c) == 3 || g.getNeighbors(r, c) == 2)))
                        tempBoard[r][c] = '1';
                    // all other cases the cell dies
                    else
                        tempBoard[r][c] = '0';
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Generation " + (i + 1));
            // Set the new gameboard as the tempboard all at once after checking the conditions for each dimenison
            try {
                Thread.sleep(t);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {

            g.setGameBoard(tempBoard);
            }
            g.printGameBoard();

        }
    }
}
```

What is supposed to happen is, the glider (or shape if you will) moves along a gameboard that I have set up. It works perfectly, however I need to slow down execution between each generation. Then when I implement the sleep method, the glider doesn't move at all.

Comment: The code in the `catch` looks like it shouldn’t be there. It should be after the `catch` block.

Comment: Why are you adding a sleep? In your loop? And why bother creating a class, if you're going to manipulate the array it holds directly?

Comment: Wow. Thank you! Can you explain why it wouldnt work before? @JohnnyMopp

Comment: As it is, the line `g.setGameBoard(tempBoard)` will only get executed if an exception is thrown. Which is unlikely to happen.